# What image file types does WebMatrix's WebImage Helper support?

Tags: c#, post, webmatrix, webimage

What image file types does WebMatrix's WebImage Helper support, when using `WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();`?

I have looked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.getimagefromrequest(v=vs.111).aspx but it didn't really provide any useful information (other than that you can request by file name, which I already knew).

I know that the following file types are accepted: ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", & ".gif"

I know that the following file types are not supported: ".ico", any non-image related file extension.

Are there any other supported or unsupported image file types that are not listed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebImage helper will attempt to return an image from any file that has an [image MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image).

Comment: I see... That makes sense, although I don't think I really saw .bmp in the list of image file types in the link you gave.

Comment: The Mime Type for a bmp file can be `image/bmp` (http://filext.com/file-extension/BMP). The list I linked to only includes MIME types that have been registered with IANA.